ASP.NET Core Web API : call unauthorized on certain machines/networks
I developed an ASP.NET Core application that consumes an API from a remote application. The API uses authentication and works as expected when tested with Postman from my development machine. However, when running the app in debug mode or as a hosted IIS application, I get an error from the API:

Unauthorized (401)

Observations

The app works successfully on 2 PCs with dynamic IPs, even on different networks.
The app does not work on 4 other PCs, even with identical code and configuration, including one on a dynamic IP (no firewall).
The same object code is deployed across all machines, ruling out code differences.

Questions

What could cause the API to respond with Unauthorized (401) from certain machines, even when all configurations and code are identical?
Could there be subtle network, OS, or IIS-level differences I'm missing?
What additional steps can I take to diagnose or resolve this issue?

What I've tried

Network Difference
Tested with 3 different networks (dynamic IP, static IP with a firewall, etc.). On one PC with a dynamic IP, it works, but on another with the same setup, it doesn't.

Authentication
The same credentials and authentication methods are used across all instances.

Local machine settings
No special certificates, proxies, or environment variables are in use.

Environment-specific dependencies
None observed, as the app is straightforward and doesn't rely on external system dependencies.

IIS configuration
Identical across all machines. Anonymous authentication is enabled, and Windows Authentication is not required.

Outbound IP whitelisting
The API provider doesn't appear to enforce IP restrictions. The issue occurs on machines with different IPs (dynamic and static).

Headers
Inspected outgoing headers with tools like Postman and Fiddler. They're identical across working and non-working instances.

Certificates
The API responds to HTTP requests where it works, so SSL/TLS isn't a factor.

Debugging
Logs consistently show an Unauthorized (401) response on failing instances, with no further details from the API.



Impossible for others to guess what’s wrong. In the end, who returns 401 responses know the answer.

I have written a blog post about Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication issues in ASP.NET Core https://nestenius.se/net/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/
Another factor is the clock, if the clocks are different, then you will have a problem too.

Could also be if there is any max length restrictions on the authoriation request header.  Tokens can be quite big if yo you are not careful.

@ToreNestenius May be its the case, I haven't checked for the difference in clock time. Let me check that.

See my blog post above, what does the WWW-Authenticate: header say?
